debug error on mac m1 "doesn't contain any 'host' platform architectures"
, I have done every thing on solana site  said (https://solana.com/docs/programs/debugging) to try to debug and can't continue cuz this error appears , the same with a other notebook with intel architecture ,any idea? thanks


great .........
